# How to display two unsynchronized datasets in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have two datasets (x: time, y: value) and I want to display them in a single line chart.
The problem is that the datasets aren't synchronized (one time, two values).

Is it possible to make a chart where for each point on the x-axis there is only one value but two datasets are displayed?

For illustration, this is the result I want:
[illustration of the desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUDWP.png)

I tried to make the chart like this, but the X axis didn't even draw. The datapoints had the correct Y value but their X value appeared to be undefined

```
function drawChart() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart1');
    chartObjects.push(new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'value 0',
                data: sensorModulesDict[sensorIDs[0]].map(item => ({ x: item.time, y: item.co2 })),
                borderColor: '#81D929',
            },
            {
                label: 'value 1',
                data: sensorModulesDict[sensorIDs[1]].map(item => ({ x: item.time, y: item.co2 })),
                borderColor: '#E67417',
            },
            ]
        },
        options: {
        }
    }));
}
```

Result of my attempt:
[result of my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT9lO.png)

Getting the array of {x,y} objects is a bit complicated due to other aspects of my code, but I checked in console and the array is correct.
[console output of my data array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzEz6.png)

Comment: It seems you want to use a time scale but it's not defined. https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/zYMWLXx

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

thanks @user2057925 for the comment, switching x-axis type to 'time' and linking the correct time adapter solved the issue